# How do i send mail with custom Form Data using WordPress

Tags: email

I have a custom HTML form with input types and checkboxes. When I submit this form I want to send a mail will all the form details from the same php. How do I send the email from WordPress? I am pretty new and would thank for ur help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`wp_mail` is the function you are looking for.

You can take the posted form data (`$_POST['email']`, for example) and then use it to build and execute the `wp_mail` function. The example below was taken from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#user-contributed-notes

```
$to = $_POST['email']; //sendto@example.com
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Also the above script would need to check for malicious attacks or bad input from the user but the `wp_mail` function will allow you to send email.

Source: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: do i add it to the same php file as my form?

Comment: It depends on how you are handling your forms. If you have the same PHP running on the template page as your form then you can (though I wouldn't recommend it). I would check out these two links for an idea on how to handle forms in PHP (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp). You can also use a plugin like Contact Form 7 (https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) if you want to not write the PHP and just work within the WP-Admin.

Comment: Thanks can i write the body as a custom html so that my mail can look unique?

Comment: @Sourav Yes you would insert that into the $body.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write your own code (and the mail form), consider a 'contact form' plugin. I use (and recommend) the Contact Form 7 plugin. It allows you to create any form, customize the look/feel/fields, and the mail that is sent out. Very powerful and popular plugin. Lots of other plugins available to add additional fields.

The only minor issue is sparse and sometimes hard-to-find (and sometimes older) technical documentation (like available filters). But I've worked around that.

Comment: well i have a custom form can i use contact form plugin to send the mails ?

Comment: You will have to 'build' the form via the plugin's interface. Although it might be possible to use CF7's 'submit' process, you would have to set many CF7 variables for it to work well, and those variables are not well-documented; you'd have to go through their code. Easiest to use CF7's form builder, I'd think.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to post a form is to use a form backend service like https://www.formkeep.com

All you have to do is modify the action tag in your form and backend service will store the data and provide ways to integrate data with the other systems.

Here's a sample for how to modify the form html. You would just replace "example token" with a key provided by the formkeep service

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://formkeep.com/f/exampletoken" method="POST">
```